# Is there a way to get the splitting records and attributes for each tree in random forest in R?

Tags: r, tree, random-forest

For producing random forest the algorithm splits randomly the records and and attributes and builds decision tree. 
For example if I use the following code:

```
set.seed(71) 
rf <-randomForest(income~.,data=mydata, ntree=200)
```

I'll have 200 trees. 
I can use the parameters **mtry** = number of variables selected at each split and **sampsize** = Sample size to be drawn from the data for growing each decision tree.
I would like to have for each of the 200 trees the numbers of lines (records) of `mydata` dataset that were chosen and the names of variables (attributes) that   were chosen. How can I find it?

Comment: `getTree` is a function that extracts the structure of a tree from a `randomForest` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your settings in mtry/sampsize you can use the following code:

```
rf = randomForest(Species~.,data=iris,ntree=200,mtry=2,sampsize=30,keep.forest=TRUE,replace=FALSE,keep.inbag=TRUE)

out_vars = varUsed(rf,by.tree=TRUE) # gives the variables used in each tree
apply(out_vars,2,function(x) which(x!=0))

out_case = rf$inbag # gives the cases used in each tree
apply(out_case,2,function(x) which(x!=0))
```

Make sure you select `keep.inbag=TRUE` and `replace=FALSE`, see `?randomForest` for documentation

Comment: Thaks  a lot @timfaber. I'm interested in the records and variables upon which the tree is constructed and not in the tree itself. Is there a way to get the source records and variables (partial mini dataset) upon which each tree of the forest is constructed?

Comment: You can get the unique values used by looking at the `split var` column or by looking at `varUsed(rf,by.tree=TRUE)`, not sure about the unique records, let me have a look

Comment: Thanks again. So, In my case where I have 200 trees. How can I get for the first tree for instance, the relevant records and attributes in the following format: tree[1] is base on mydata lines: 5, 8, 102. and mydata attributes: att1, att8, att19? and for tree[2] the relevant lines and attributes?

Comment: Ha, did not knot this but it's actually in the documentation. If selecting `keep.inbag=TRUE` (while having replace as `FALSE` because it only provides unique samples) you can get the samples. Updated the example